# Error phpMyAdmin: '¡Usted no tiene los privilegios para administrar a los usuarios!'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, phpmyadmin

Vengo a preguntaros por qué me aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He estado ojeando por internet, y veo que proponen soluciones que tienen que ver con la propia base de datos SQL, usando **comandos para otorgar privilegios**. El problema es que esta base de datos en concreto, "**condominium**", la he creado yo ahora mismo desde **phpMyAdmin**. ¿Por qué no me deja? ¿Tiene que ver aun así con los comandos de **SQL**? Añado también que ejecuto el control panel de **XAMPP como Administrador.**

Alguna idea? Gracias de antemano.

EDIT: Pestaña cuentas de usuario.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la barra superior haz click en **Servidor: 127.0.0.1**. Prueba accediendo por la pestaña cuentas de usuario y haz click en la columna acción, opción editar privilegios, desde allí puedes cambiar, tanto los privilegios de usuario como a que bases de datos puede acceder. Estas logueado como usuario **root** en phpmyadmin?

Comment: Antes de probar te contesto y ya me dices. Sí, estoy logueado como root. Bueno, adjunto una foto de qué me aparece y a ver que opinas.

Comment: temgo el mismo problema, me dice que no tengo permiso para administrar a los usuarios

Comment: Intenta ejecutando esta sentencia:
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost';